# Limit at $\theta \rightarrow 0$ is showing that $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}X^2_i$. is not the MLE?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation

Let $\mathbf X = (X_1, . . . , X_n)$ consist of independent and identically Normal $N(0, θ)$ random
variables, with mean $0$ and variance $θ > 0.$

The density of $f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{(2\pi \theta)^{\frac{n}{2}}} e^{\frac{1}{2 \theta} \sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i}$$

So, I have to show that the MLE for $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}X^2_i$.

I have showed that the derivative of the log-likelihood function is equal to $0$ when $\theta$ is evaluated at $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}X^2_i$. Then I showed that it is the maximum by showing the second derivative is less than $0$ . Then by computing the limit of the likelihood function, when $\theta \rightarrow \infty$ I showed that it's $0$. Then only thing left to do is to compute the limit when $\theta \rightarrow 0$. But when I compute it, for some reason it diverges to $\infty$. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: First of all, you lost minus in exponent. If $\theta\to 0$, $e^{-1/\theta}=\frac{1}{e^{1/\theta}}\to 0$ very fast. And $\frac{1}{\theta^{n/2}}e^{-c/\theta}\to 0$, where $c>0$.

Comment: @NCh yes, the lost minus in the exponent was a typo, thanks! But doesnt $\frac{1}{\theta^{n/2}}$ diverge when $\theta \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Replace $1/\theta=x\to +\infty$ and consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{n/2}\cdot e^{-x}=0$.

Comment: @NCh oh okay, thanks for that:)